# МСВС скрывает диски Windows

Tags: windows-7

Стоит windows 7, поставил МСВС, теперь диски винды скрытые и она не грузится. Как "подружить" эти две системы?

Comment: Вероятнее всего, изменены типы разделов (байт признака типа в МБР). Если так - то восстановить... до следующего запуска МСВС.

Comment: Если восстановить то lilo перестаёт работать

Comment: Ну остаётся кому-то копать доку по МСВС и его lilo на предмет регистрации там дополнительных ОС...